# Using @NamedEntityGraph reloads all properties

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

We are using `@NamedEntityGraph` extensively in our applications. Now we have found a side effect.

When setting a loaded property, before persisting the update, a special logger logs the changes. Therefore it touches also not loaded properties (lazy loaded).

In this step, `Eclipselink` loads all properties from the database.
This results in overwriting the changed properties with the values from the database. In the end the changes are not happening at all.
How can we avoid to load all properties from the database or not overwriting the ones already changed?

Our `JPA` implementation is `Eclipselink`.

Comment: Overwriting should not occur, and would only happen if you've done something that would trigger a refresh.  Refreshes cause potential oddities with lazy relationships, as they can cascade when eventually triggered and seem strange when they occur well after the initial refresh query.  If this isn't happening, more details are required as I don't see how you can change properties and have them be overwritten by entity graphs or fetch groups in a simple model.

Comment: the refresh happens when getting a not loaded property. I circumvented this behaviour now by checking in the logger with PersistenceUnitUtil.isLoaded method.

Comment: yes, which should only happen as I mentioned, if you have a relationship that is cascading the refresh somehow.  If you've got a workaround, great, otherwise show more information if it is an open question.